# Single Sign On(OAuth) for Docker hub

Tags: docker, oauth-2.0

For past few days I am researching the Docker API documentation, I could not find a Proper instruction to get `client_id`, `client_secret` and Scopes list to get AccessToken.

I have done SSO using Google, Azure, Github, Gitlab now I am trying same using Docker but seems tough. Is there is any proper guidance to get AccessToken and RefreshToken?